# converting a weird std::string into an NSString

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsstring, stdstring

I have a weird situation where I am trying to convert an std::string into an NSString.

I have tried the usual method which generally works which is:
[NSString stringWithUTF8String: myCppString.c_str()];

However, I am getting nil returned. I think it has something to do with weird characters. This is mostly because I have seen the following in the data on investigation:

[image]

Notice the upsidedown question marks. I tried another call that I found when looking through SO but it too did not work: [NSString stringWithCString:myCppString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

I can print the string out as a const char * and as a std::string as you saw from the logs. The c++ string was made with an ostringstream if that has any impact. The data comes from a server which should be UTF-8 and is fed through json into a sqlite database.

Do you have any advice on how I can get the NSString to work?

=== [EDIT] ===
This is what came up for the hex data for one particular reason with upside-down question-marks.

[image]

Comment: A hex dump would help determine the encoding and the unprintable characters.

Comment: If you supply the hex dump please copy/paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the weird characters represented non-existent  that was being read in in my particular case I was reading a map key and didn't check if the find command returned a myMap.end().

Thank you for your time in reviewing my question.